# Existence of subsequences $a_{n_k}$ that converges to a value between $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am stuck on this question:

Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence with $\liminf a_n=s$ and $\limsup a_n=t$ where $s$ and $t$ are real number. Then there must exist some subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that converges to $c$ where $s<c<t$.

For example, if $\lim\inf a_n=1$ and $\lim\sup a_n=3$, then does there exist a subsequence that converges to 2?

I think it is yes, because every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. However, I am not fully sure how to argue it.

Comment: how about 1,3,1,3,1,... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Then, $\liminf a_n =-1$, $\limsup a_n =1$.

However, any converging subsequence converges to either $-1$ or $1$.

Comment: What about lim inf and lim sub with both positive numbers, such as 1 and 3 respectively?

Comment: See @Alan's comment.
You could simply define $a_n=2+(-1)^n$